# iOS Development using Visual Studio.Net

Tags: .net, ios, frameworks, evaluation

I have a new mobile application I need to get out the door but I need to utilize our VS.Net IDE to build the application.

This app needs to have iOS UI features and functionality.

It needs to be developed in VS.Net (2010 or 2012 - does not matter).

I am open to utilizing reasonable multiple steps to build this application but I am not interested in going down the Objective-C route (if I do that then I am doing it on a mac).

Here is what I have looked at so far and some general notes:

iOS Build Environment
http://www.pmbaty.com/iosbuildenv/

- Objective-C
- Tools to create initial project in C with a vcproj file
- Uncertain which version of VS.Net this is supposed to support as 2010/2012 both wanted to convert
- Requires switching back and forth between tools and VS.Net
- Significant training upscale required: Objective-C, new Tools

Visual Web GUI
http://www.visualwebgui.com/tabid/711/Default.aspx

- New project type for VS.Net 2010
- Has own set of controls which have to use and none others
- Easy to draw UI using an old style designer implementation for winforms
- Attempted to run project but only ever gave listing of project directory in browser
- Coding is in C# similar to any winforms project
- Significant waste of time - not very intuitive

Nomad - VS.Net Extension (probably most simple use of vs.net)
http://www.vsnomad.com/documentation/index.html

- New project type for VS.Net 2010
- Utilizes Html as the document type with Html controls
- Links in jquery and cordova (phonegap)
- Basically a phonegap project for VS.Net
- Requires Apple Dev membership (certs, etc) in order to build iOS apps
- Coding is Javascript
- Does allow you to build from VS.Net providing you have Provisioning Profiles and Signing Certs
- Has possibilities but significant training upscale as learning phonegap would be needed

Studio for iPhone - ComponentOne
http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioiPhone/Demos/

- Utilizes Asp.Net projects
- Does not work well in design mode - almost like totally integrated into VS.Net
- Had to add controls to the project which was strange
- Got 1/2 through the demo before I realized this is ONLY iPhone and not device indifferent
- Not so intuitive to work with but workable and the output is very nice
- Has possibilities but this feels like hacking Asp.net - probably just me

**What I am looking for is either other options or confirmation I have covered the main ones so I can move on perhaps use something like PhoneGap, Sencha or? **

Comment: would not be cheaper and more reliable to develop on a Mac...?

Comment: @holex - I am looking into that as well.  That's a whole different silo to learn which is fine but I need to exhaust the in house dev platform first - justify changing that is - thanks!

Comment: @Nacereddine - that's on my list though I am uncertain of the whole development work flow - something I am exploring - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch/) project by Xamarin. It allows to use a lot of .NET features in iOS. You can open your VS2010 project in MonoDevelop, compile it there and deploy it to the iDevice. Although, it is not free. The price for a single Professional license is $399 USD.

Comment: Good point - I looked at it and it's far enough away from VS.net in terms of ramp up that I may just try to justify doing pure iOS development- thanks

Comment: It should also be noted that this solution will require a networked Apple Mac as well as a Windows machine. As per Xamarin's website: "iOS applications cannot be created without Apple’s compiler, and they cannot be deployed without Apple’s certificates and code-signing tools. This means that your Xamarin iOS for Visual Studio installation requires a networked Mac OS-X computer to perform these tasks for you. Once configured, Xamarin’s tools will make the process as seamless as possible, but the fact remains that a Mac is required in addition to the Windows computer running Visual Studio."